# Change a files permission to write

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Can anyone tell me how to change a files permission to write access in Ubuntu? I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the files location

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/moviepy/video/fx/resize.py
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the file permission you use the `chmod` command followed by the value.

To change the file to write access you can use

`chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/moviepy/video/fx/resize.py`

**BEWARE** this will make the file write-able to anyone!

More about file permissions here https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: Thanks. I get 'operation not permitted'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod a+w fileName //gives write permission to everyone
```

Like you can decide whether you want to give the permission to user(u), group(g) or other(o) to give right to
read(r), write(w), execute(x)
`+` to give permission and `-` to deny them
in general it will be

```
chmod member +/- permissions
```